# How to insert in bigquery using pandas data frame in cron job on server

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, google-bigquery

i am using this pandas to_gbq method. It works when i run manually but in cron job on server it won't run. please help.

```
audience = {'adaccount_id':adaccount_id ,
            'audience_id': audience_id,
            'audience_name': audience_name,
            'audience_size':audience_size,
            'created_at':created_at }

audience_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(audience)


##### inserting into bigquery###########
audience_dataframe.to_gbq('fb_raw_data.audience_size', 
                          'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                          if_exists='replace',
                          private_key = r'C:\Users\Vikas Chauhan\Desktop\contact\New folder\private_key.json')
```

This works when i use it manually. But in cron job it doesn't work.

Comment: Identifying why a cron job is not working can be quite a tough job (no pun intended). Probably it's not something related to your code but rather to environment variables (when a cron job is running it runs on a different environment that you use regularly: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables)
You can try inserting in your code a `try except` and writing the exception to a txt file as a debug method. Other methods are outlined in the previous link.

Comment: my cron job is working properly but in that cron the above code is not running

Comment: I pasted the wrong link x.x! sorry for that. Here it is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work
It has some techniques to debug what could be wrong. Usually what I do is I put a **try except** in the code and write the error to a txt file. And from that I identify whether the cron is not running or something went wrong in the script (most likely it's some environment variable that is not defined in the cron setup)